# DAX Creating Calendar Table With Additional Field

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm creating a calendar table in DAX:

```
Dates =
CALENDAR (
    MIN ( 'Work Weeks'[Start Date].[Date] ),
    MAX ( 'Work Weeks'[Start Date].[Date] )
)
```

The work weeks table contains a week number and a start date for each week.

For each date in my new Dates table, I want to assign a work week number using the start date of the work week. Note that work weeks start on different days of the week (they're assigned properly in my work weeks table though).

So what I'm trying is:

```
Dates =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDAR (
        MIN ( 'Work Weeks'[Start Date].[Date] ),
        MAX ( 'Work Weeks'[Start Date].[Date] )
    ),
    "Work Week",
        CALCULATE (
            MAX ( 'Work Weeks'[Start Date].[Date] ),
            'Work Weeks'[Start Date] <= Date
        )
)
```

I'm not sure how to reference the current row/date in the condition at the end. And then I also need to return the work week number, rather than just the start date.

Comment: It looks like you are creating a Date table but are still keeping Auto Date/Time. Implementing a Date table is a best practice, but you should also disable the Auto Date/Time. This article might help https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/automatic-time-intelligence-in-power-bi/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your work week table looks something like this:

[image]

You can use this date table code to add the week number:

```
Date Table = 
VAR ListOfDate = 
    VAR MinDate = MIN ( Sales[Order Date] ) -- Replace the reference with the column of your model
    VAR MaxDate = MAX ( Sales[Order Date] ) -- Replace the reference with the column of your model
    VAR StartDate = DATE ( 2021, 1, 1 ) -- DATE ( YEAR ( MinDate ), 1, 1 )
    VAR EndDate = DATE ( 2021, 12, 31 ) -- DATE ( YEAR ( MaxDate ), 12, 31 )
    VAR Result = CALENDAR ( StartDate, EndDate )
    RETURN
        Result
VAR WorkWeekTable = ALL ( WorkWeek )
VAR CalendarTable = 
    GENERATE ( 
        ListOfDate,
        VAR CurrentDate = [Date]
        RETURN
            ROW ( 
                "Calendar Year Number", YEAR ( CurrentDate ),
                "Calendar Month Number", MONTH ( CurrentDate ),
                "Work week", 
                    CALCULATE ( 
                        MIN ( WorkWeek[Work Week Number] ),
                        CurrentDate >= WorkWeek[Work Week Start Date],
                        CurrentDate <= WorkWeek[Work Week End Date],
                        REMOVEFILTERS ( )
                    ) 
            )
    )
RETURN
    CalendarTable
```

The result will look like this:

[image]